# Validating custom component in angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was working in angular project, There I had come across a situation in which I need to validate custom component having a textbox.

```
<dollar-text-validate ng-model="ctrl.value" required name="myDir"></dollar-text-validate>
```

**My Component**

angular.module("myApp", []);

```
    angular.module("myApp").controller('MyController',function(){
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.value = 56;
    });

    angular.module("myApp").component('dollarTextValidate',{
        bindings: {
            ngModel :'='
        },
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-focus="ctrl.focus()" ng-blur="ctrl.blur()" ng-model="ctrl.amount1"><input type="hidden" ng-model="ctrl.ngModel"></div>',
        controller: function() {
            var ctrl = this;
            // ctrl.amount1 = 
            ctrl.amount1 =ctrl.ngModel===undefined||ctrl.ngModel==='' ? '' :'$'+ctrl.ngModel;
            console.log(ctrl.ngModel);
            ctrl.focus=function(){
                ctrl.amount1 = ctrl.amount1 === undefined ? '' : ctrl.amount1.slice(1);
                ctrl.ngModel = ctrl.amount1;
                console.log(ctrl.ngModel);
            }

            ctrl.blur=function(){
                ctrl.ngModel = ctrl.amount1;
                ctrl.amount1 = ctrl.amount1==='' ? '' :'$'+ctrl.ngModel;
                console.log(ctrl.ngModel);
            }
        },
        controllerAs:'ctrl'
    })
```

This component is used to set $ symbol in front of entered value. So $ appended value will be available in textbox and original value which is to be validated in hidden field.

How can I validate hidden field. I tried with required attribute in hidden tag but nothing happening. Also tried with custom tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to break it to you, but you might wanna go for directive, and then use $parsers, $formatter and $validators properties of ngModelController.

Component can be used for this, but it is just easier with normal directive.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module("myApp").directive('dollarTextValidate', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      var regexp = /^\$(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/;
      var ngModel = $element.controller('ngModel');
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value ? '$' + value : '';
      });
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        var matched = value.match(regexp);

        if (matched) {
          return +matched[1];
        }
      });

      ngModel.$validators.greaterThan10 = function (modelVal, viewVal) {
        var value = modelVal || viewVal;
        
        return value > 10;
      };
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-form="form">
  dollar-text-validate = <input dollar-text-validate ng-model="value" required name="myDir"><br>
  number input = <input type="number" ng-model="value" required><br>
  value = {{value}}<br>
  errors = {{form.myDir.$error}}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, cos You would have to play a little bit with component to achieve something that is easy with attribute directive and some features of ng-model. Not to mention you avoid need for template and extra watcher, so it is more performance wise to use attribute directive. But ofc it is still possible with component.

Comment: Component binding is taking more time than directive. So directives are best for my requirement. Thanks @sielakos